# Manipulating a product term inside an integral

Tags: integration

I have an expression of the form
$$P(x) = \int_0^\infty \prod_{i=0}^{n} e^{-G(a, x_i)}\,\mathrm{d}a $$
and I was wondering if there was any way that I could swap the order of the product and the integral? I suspect not but its been a while since I had to manipulate integrals for myself. Ideally P(x) will represent the total probability of making i measurements from a Possion distributed system with zero occurences each time.

Comment: In general, $\int fg \not= \int f \int g$.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was probably the case.

Comment: 1. I think you mean $\prod_{i=0}^N$?! 2. Would it help to write $e^{-\sum G }$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is a CW answer intended to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

As [AlexE remarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99509/manipulating-a-product-term-inside-an-integral#comment234166_99509), there is no general way to swap products and integrals.

This means that in general, evaluating integrals like the one stated can be quite hard, especially if the mapping $G$ is not in some way "nice".